# Groups of order $p^5$

Tags: group-theory, p-groups, groups-enumeration

I am reading a paper "A Determination of order $p^5$" by H A Bender ($p$ is an odd prime). He divides the classification in two classes, one which contains an abelian subgroup of order $p^4$ and other do not. He assumes an element of order $p$ which operates on this subgroup and this element together with a subgroup of order $p^4$ generates the group of order $p^5$. Now my problem is how to guarantee that there exists an element of order $p$ outside this subbgroup of order $p^4$.

Comment: Hmm, does he assume $p$ odd? Otherwise this is not true (the generalized queternion groups have a unique element of order $2$, which will be contained in any subgroup of index $2$).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft yes, this is mention in the question.

Comment: Ahh, of course. Not sure how I missed that.

Comment: I don't think it is true. For all odd primes $p$ there are nonsplit extensions of an elementary abelian group of order $p^4$ by a group of order $p$. You should check again exactly what he is claiming.