# On classification of groups of order $p^5$

Tags: finite-groups, abelian-groups, group-presentation, p-groups, metabelian-groups

Can someone suggest me some source where the author has classified all non-isomorphic groups of order $p^5$ ?

Edit 1 : I need complete classification (not upto isoclinism), and also in finitely presented form . I found that with increase in value of prime $p$, number of groups increases. So, can we completely classify all groups of order $p^5$ for any prime $p$, in finitely presented form or get their structure description ?

Comment: Yes, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/601203/groups-of-order-p5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several papers in the literature on the classification of groups of order $p^5$. For example,

R. James, The groups of order $p^6$ (p an odd prime), Math. Comp. 34 (1980), 613-637,

also contains the case $p^5$.

Comment: Thanks.Your answer is very helpful for me. If there are some more articles which you can suggest , showing their structures in the form of semi-direct products or central products ?

Comment: The above article conatins classification upto isoclinism. Can you suggest me some source where I can find complete classification of group of order $p^5$. Actually I need them in finitely presented form. But with rise in value of prime $p$, no. of groups of order $p^5$ also increases. So how can I classify all groups of order $p^5$ in finitely presented form ? Please help me out.